# Using a variable in a formula in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, module

I am having a problem with a piece of code that I’m writing.  I have created a “parent” workbook which will be used by multiple users as the basis for some basic reporting.  This workbook creates a number of child workbooks by VBA.  The end users then enter values in these child workbooks, which are aggregated in the parent workbook.

However, I am having trouble with using a variable in a formula.  If I use a formula such as (eg)

```
ActiveCell.Formula = “=S:\ThisIs\AnExample\FilePath\Name.xlsx”
```

then the formula works fine.  However, what I need to do is change the path so that “Name” in the example above is actually a variable (fname, which is a global [string] variable).

I thought something like

```
ActiveCell.Formula = “=S:\ThisIs\AnExample\FilePath\”& fname&”.xlsx”
```

(with a few brackets in relevant places) would do the trick, as that’s what seems to recommended in the responses I’ve seen to similar questions – but I’ve tried all sorts of permutations of bracketing of the above, none of which will do what I want.

Comment: What's the issue with the example you posted? Providing `fname` has a string assigned to it, there's no reason why `"=YourPath" & fname & ".xlsx"` shouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I try to run the code I get this error ...Run TIme error '1004: Application-defined or object-defined error'. Does that help?

Comment: Could you update your question with the relevant code along with which line the error is occurring on please?

Comment: I have just solved this, I don't know how. Going on your comment that it should work, I just copied the code, deleted it, pasted it back in again, and it worked! I have no idea why it suddenly decided to work. Thank you for your help, I appreciate the time you've taken.(Really, I should say you solved it for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be on the safe side you could declare "Dim fname As String" and double-check the fname to make sure it is stripped from extension and generally trimmed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say using a hardcoded path instead of a mapped path would be more reliable, if that is an option. It would prevent issues that would occur if a logon script failed to map the same drive letter to the specific network path the resource is stored in.